# Difference between Controller action and Webapi controller action ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am beginner in web application development. I was told to write an end point in ASP.NET MVC 5 Project which needs to be called from a **desktop app**.

So, below is what I did
In

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ClearCoInfo(int id)
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

**In WebAPI Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    public  IHttpActionResult  ClearCoInfo(int id)
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Now I want to know what's the difference between above two approach and which is the correct approach.
Because I am able to access both via a URL. Please guide me.

Comment: That does  not answer my question. As I do not want a view to be returned. I just want one data (integer) to be passed from my desktop app to the web controller action.

Comment: So can I use any of the above approach

Comment: I want to know what's the difference in context to my scenario where if I use controller or webapi controller. Can I not call the normal controller action method from desktop app? Does it mandatorily needs to be WebApiController action?